# Add image file programmatically in drupal 6

Tags: 6, forms, media, files

i want to upload an image on my site. I have a custom form in a module with

```
  $form['picture'] = array(
  '#type'   => 'file',
  '#title'  => t('Avatar'),
  '#prefix' => '<img src="' . $user->picture . '">'
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = 'product_validate_picture';
```

and in my validate fucntion :

```
$validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg png'),
                    'file_validate_image_resolution' => array('500x500'));

$file = file_save_upload('picture', $validators);
dsm($file);
```

The problem is that i do not get the picture returned by the form, i only get "0" which is an error. So, did i do something wrong, or another method is better to get and save a picture returned by a custom form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a sample for implement it in drupal 6

maybe your problem occur because of 2 thing,

- permission of directory
- $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");

made this example for you...explain how to working with cvs

```
   /**
    * Form function  
    */
     function _form_cvs_import($form_state) {
      $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
      $form['container'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset', 
        '#title' => t('CVS UPLOAD') , 
      );
      $form['container']['cvs_file'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file' ,  
        '#title' => t('CVS FILE') , 
        '#description' => t('insert your cvs file here') , 
      ) ;   
      $form['container']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit' ,  
        '#value' => t('SEND') , 
      ) ;       

       return $form ; 
    }

/**
* form validate
*/
function _form_cvs_import_validate($form, $form_state) {
 $validators = array(
  'file_validate_extensions' => array('cvs'),
 );
 if(!file_save_upload('cvs_file', $validators)) { // the file is not submitted
    form_set_error('cvs_file', 'Please select the cvs file') ;  
 }else{ // the file is submitted another validation for extension
   $file = file_save_upload('cvs_file', $validators, file_directory_path()) ; 
   if($file->filemime != 'application/octet-stream' ) {
     form_set_error('cvs_file', 'Extensions Allowed : cvs') ;       
   }        
 }      
}


/**
*  form submit
*/
function _form_cvs_import_submit($form, $form_state) {
    $file = file_save_upload('cvs_file', $validators, file_directory_path()) ;  // this is the cvs file in the tmp directory
    $file_handler = fopen($file->filepath, 'r') ; // open this cvs file
    $line_num = 0 ;
    $fields = array() ;  
    while(!feof($file_handler)) { 
        $line_num++ ; 
        $line = fgets($file_handler) ; // this is the line/row
        $line_array = explode(",", $line);  //  array of row fields
        $field_num = 0 ;  
        foreach($line_array as $field) { 
            $field_num++ ; 
            $fields[$line_num][$field_num] = str_replace('"', '', $field );  // E.g you can access second row and third field by $fields[2][3]
        }   
    }
    fclose($file_handler);
    unlink($file->filepath);
```

}

Comment: Sorry for late return, i do not work on a single project... The problem was the form enctype: 
$form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");
Without it, the $file always return 0 instead of the object file. So problem solve, many thx!

Answer (score 2):

This is not good job save file in validation phase and really  where you get file from posted data ? 
file exist in `$form_state['value']['picture]`

mybe below code help you

```
function yourmodule_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    $file = $form_state['values']['picture'];

    $validators = array();
    $file = file_save_upload('file', $validators, 'public://');
....
```

Comment: @Clive I didn't notice that he using drupal 6. :(

Comment: Sorry but this is incorrect - Both Drupal 6 and 7 use validate handlers to move/save uploaded pictures. See [`user_validate_picture()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_validate_picture/6)

Comment: It's the same for Drupal 7, uploaded files get handled in the validate handler then persisted in the submit handler. "Incorrect" might be too strong, perhaps better to say that this isn't the "best" way to do it, simply because core does things differently. This will still work. I think semantically this _does_ belong in the validation step, because it's validating the picture whilst saving

Comment: @Clive  yes,I agree with you.tnx :)

Comment: I did not want to use it into the validate, but i search for example and everywhere, they validate it before sending it to the form_submit. As you suggest in the other post, i'll try to change the right on the folder and save it into my node from there. thx

Comment: @SavaryNicolas do u check my other answers?